# AWS Windows EC2 Instance is not connecting to internet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, virtual-machine, internet-connection

I am having a EC2 Windows instance in my AWS account. I have used 2019 base to create my machine, I am able to connect to my machine and I do not have internet connectivity in the instance. I am new to AWS, kindly provide your inputs to resolve the issue.

Comment: When you say "I am able to connect to my machine", are you connecting from your own computer on the Internet? If so, the instance _does_ have Internet connectivity. What specifically are you trying to do when you say that it does not work, and what error messages are you receiving?

Answer (score 1):

Check whether you have created NAT gateway, and also check whether it is in available state. And also NAT should be created in Public subnet. Check these settings. And also check whether you are allowing outbound traffic to internet.

Comment: I am facing same issue .. Created Windows EC2 instance .. with following details

Answer (score 0):

As you said you able to connect to your instance that means your instance have public IP. 
I think your instance able to connect internet.
I guess you are facing issue when using IE browser? That why you think your instance not able to connect internet. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes I am using IE browser only. Is that an issue ? Should I try out connecting in chrome ?

Answer (score 0):

On "Server Manager" open "Local Server". Go to IE Explore Enhanced Security Configuration and switch it to off. Please see image below. 
This cause made you unable to connect internet via IE.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KI2TS.png)